# Need help with JavaScript `{` indentation

Tags: indentation, javascript

I'd need some guidance with adjusting my indentation settings for js-mode (JavaScript).  It should basically look like C/C++'s Stroustrup mode. Most of it works as expected, however there are some cases that are not indented as expected:

1. Indentation of multi-line initialiters `{` should start at column of declaration (`var` or `const`):

   ```js
   function make_curve (id, color, fillColor)
   {                         // correct
       const en =            // correct
       {                     // desired
             {               // current, wrong
   ```

   The indentation does match with `const en = {`but I very much prefer to put `{` in an extra line and align `{` with the matching `}`.
2. Opening brace of function body should be aligned with `function` keyword. Example:

   ```js
   window.animate
       = (window.requestAnimationFrame
          || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
          || ...
          || function (callback)
             {           // desired
          {              // current wrong
   ```

My current setup is:

```lisp
(defun my-js-mode-hook ()
  (interactive)
  (setq tab-width 4
        ;; this will make sure TABs are used instead of spaces
        indent-tabs-mode t)
  )

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation in `js2-mode` is not as customizable as indentation in C mode. As such it's not possible to do this outside of changing the source code for `js2-mode` itself.

Like you, I like to have statements inside a function indented relative to the function keyword, so I added this code to the middle of the `js2-bounce-indent` function:

```
;; Fifth likely point:  indent from 'function' keyword on previous line.
(setq pos (save-excursion
            (forward-line -1)
            (goto-char (point-at-bol))
            (when (re-search-forward "\\s-+\\(function\\)\\s-+"
                                     (point-at-eol) t)
              (goto-char (match-beginning 1))
              (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n")
              (current-column))))
(when pos
  (cl-incf pos js2-basic-offset)
  (push pos positions))
```

You can do something similar for variables. Note especially the "second likely point", which looks for " = " on the previous line to choose an indentation point; adjusting this will let you do what you want.